# Unable to implement photo slider in theme template

Tags: views, theming

I downloaded a theme from [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/corporate_corp_theme) and I chose this theme because I wanted to builder a slider photo gallery as shown in the screen shot [here](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/corporate-corp-theme_0.png).

However, I am unable to achieve the desired effect because I am new at Drupal 7.

I have tried the following steps for implementing the photo gallery. Please help me out by pointing my mistake.

1- Identify block regions. These are as follows:

[image: Block Regions]

2- Make a content type with Image type as the field as follows:

[image: Content type for slideshow]

3- Then I placed it inside the Slide show block provided by the template as shown in the figure.

[image]

4- I even made a view and placed it inside the same Slide show block provided by the template but I am not getting the slider that I want.The previous screen shot shows the view as well.

At best, I get a picture on the front page when I choose it as 'published to front page'.

So, does this mean I cannot implement a photo slider this way? And my only option then is to use a contributed module for a photo slider?

If the latter is true then what use is the template other than a basic mark up for html and css?

Lastly, **is the solution to my problem that I use a contributed photo slider module and then place it in one of the pre-defined blocks provided by the theme?**

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did in your website is create a new content type that holds a static image for each entry. From what I see in the template link you posted, the theme you chose uses Nivo Slider as the default solution for a slider and even has an installation instructions link (which is not working).

My advice would be to follow the instruction on this link:
[Nivo Slider Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nivo_slider), and install the module yourself. It will create a new content type for you to make the slider you need.

Comment: Now the slider shows with only one picture. The remaining pictures are not moving and showing in the slider. I have configured Jquery update to use version 2.1 even. Libraries module is also installed.

The automatic scrolling is not happening.

Comment: Do I need to create a separate view for Nivo slider module as well to enable the automatic scrolling?

Comment: I have never used the module but I think all you need to do is install the Nivo Slider library into the libraries folder the module created and then upload the pictures you want to use into the new content type that came with the slider module. Have you done those things?

Comment: Yea, already did that. The slider shows and I can upload images as well, but the images don't rotate. I thought it was an issue with the Jquery update module but I am using the newer version of it and it still doesn't work. However I am going to follow the link at http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-and-configuring-views-nivo-slider-in-drupal-7/ and see if it works. This link mentions a couple of steps that I did differently.